# Which one of these rings are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

We have the follwoing ring and we need to see which one are isomorphic:-

- $\mathbb{Z[i]/(5)}$
- $F_{5}[X]/(X^2-1)$
- $F_{5}[X]/(X^2+1)$

First I thought the first one is field. but later based on answer and comments I knew that all of them are not field even they are not integral domain. So this approach not work.

Comment: Are you familiar with the general (ring theoretic) version of the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Not familiar with it but I just read it. I think we can use it to show that $F_{5}[X]/(X^2-1)\cong F_{5}[X]/(x-1) \times F_{5}[X]/(x+1)$.

Comment: Great!. Then do the same with $x^2+1=x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$.

Comment: $F_{5}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong F_{5}[x]/(x-2) \times F_{5}[x]/(x+2)$  so its look like they have same structure ( I mean 2 and 3 ).

Comment: Correct again!${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p=5$ is not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so the ideal $(5)$ is not maximal. Indeed, $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. Similarly $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$. The first and the third are isomorphic, since $\mathbb{Z}[i]\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$. What about the second one ?

Comment: Thanks for the correction to my mistake.. so now we conclude that the 1,3 can not be isomorphic to 2 since second one are field?

Comment: Also $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ is not irreducible. So they all have zero divisors. don't they ?

Comment: since they are not maximal ideal ( and prime ideal) we do not have an integral domain that is we have zero divisors.

Comment: Right. So the second one is not a field (you said this above).

Comment: Yes its not field. but also the other is not a field. I will update the post.